# Is there a way to iterate through both lists and functions?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have a function that loads data into a database that I want to iterate through a list of stock tickers, then iterate through both the stock endpoints which are used for a standardized naming convention and a list of functions that pull data from an API.

```
self.stock_tickers = ['MMM', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ABMD', 'ACN', 'ATVI', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AAP', 'AES']

self.stock_endpoints = ['one_year_daily', 'two_year_daily',
                        'one_year_weekly', 'two_year_weekly', 'three_year_weekly',
                        'one_month_daily', 'two_month_daily', 'three_month_daily', 'six_month_daily',
                        'one_day_minute', 'two_day_minute', 'three_day_minute']

self.functions = (StockEndpoints.one_year_daily(),
                  StockEndpoints.two_year_daily(),
                  StockEndpoints.one_year_weekly(),
                  StockEndpoints.two_year_weekly(),
                  StockEndpoints.three_year_weekly(),
                  StockEndpoints.one_month_daily(),
                  StockEndpoints.two_month_daily(),
                  StockEndpoints.three_month_daily(),
                  StockEndpoints.six_month_daily(),
                  StockEndpoints.one_day_min(),
                  StockEndpoints.two_day_min(),
                  StockEndpoints.three_day_min())
```

StockEndpoints() is a function in a separate class that requires the parameter (tckr) or the stock ticker being passed through.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def fill_tables(self):

    # Inserts data into their respective column
    try:
        for tckr in self.stock_tickers:
            for endpoint in self.stock_endpoints:
                query = '''INSERT INTO {}_{} (symbol, date_time, close_price, high, low, open_price, volume)
                           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''.format(tckr, endpoint)


         values = PERFORM FUNCTION THAT MATCHES THE ENDPOINT BEING ITERATED THROUGH.

             EXAMPLE: THE CURRENT ENDPOINT IS 'one_year_daily' THEREFORE I WANT TO RUN THE
             FUNCTION 'StockEndpoints.one_year_daily(tckr)'


            # Execute the sql commands to insert data
            self.cursor.executemany(query, values)
            self.conn.commit()
            print(self.cursor.rowcount, 'records inserted into {}_{}'.format(tckr, endpoint))

    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

The main issue I'm having is that lets say in the first iteration the endpoint is one_year_daily and then function is StockEndpoints.one_year_daily(tckr) then I want to go through another iteration of that stock ticker but using the endpoint two_year_daily and the function StockEndpoints.two_year_daily(tckr) and pass through the current tckr being iterated through.

I know I can do a FOR loop with the stock tickers and then another FOR loop for the stock endpoints, but then I have no idea how to iterate through functions as well and make sure they match the endpoint.

If it helps here is the function

StockEndpoints.one_year_daily(tckr)

```
def one_year_daily(self, tckr):
    self.TDSession.login()

    quote_data = self.TDSession.get_price_history(symbol=tckr,
                                                  periodType='year',
                                                  period=1,
                                                  frequencyType='daily',
                                                  frequency=1,
                                                  needExtendedHoursData='false')

    sql_data = [(tckr,
                 quote_data['candles']['datetime'],
                 quote_data['candles']['close'],
                 quote_data['candles']['high'],
                 quote_data['candles']['low'],
                 quote_data['candles']['open'],
                 quote_data['candles']['volume'])
                for x, quote_data['candles'] in enumerate(quote_data['candles'])]

    return sql_data
```

Let me know if you have any questions or if I can add or clarify things, thank you!

Comment: You can do the same thing, you just need to remove the `()` fron each of the functions so you can call them in your loop

Comment: @Nathan In my actual program they are removed, I think I must’ve copied the old section, but thank you for the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and then use the `endpoints` from your for loop

```
getattr(StockEndpoints, endpoint)(tckr)
```

Otherwise, you can create a dictionary of valid functions to endpoints and then iterate over the dictionary

```
{
   "one_year_daily": StockEndpoints.one_year_daily
}

for endpoint, func in self.stock_endpoints.items()
    func(tckr)
```

Comment: The names don't match exactly. `endpoint == 'three_day_minute'` corresponds to `StockEndPoints.three_day_min()`

Comment: @Barmar - Good spot, I've extended the answer anyway to include a dictionary lookup, but I'd imagine the OP might want to make those strings the same as the function names too

Comment: Good eye catching that, I will be sure to go through and make sure everything matches. Right now I’m just throwing a bunch of stuff together to make sure the concepts work then I’ll go through and refine everything!